# What UI component is used in this picture?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am curious about how to display both Date/Time with a layout simultaneously.
[image]

Comment: Please Add what you tried or what you already researched.

Comment: As I would design it: `LinearLayout containing TextView, TextView, TextView, GridView, TextView` (**1** Layout, **5** Views).

Comment: it is one layout inside another layout. I don't see anything difficult. What exactly is a problem?

Comment: @KlingKlang Thanks man!

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko You don't need a second layout inside the first one. Avoid unnecessary nesting, since it's bad for performances.

Comment: @KlingKlang, I don't agree with you. In fact GridView will have 7 nested layouts. Additionally, GridView itself is a ViewGroup, so I don;t think that there is a place to mention nesting of views.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko **NO**. It's only a GridView with 7 TextViews using **compund drawables** (`android:drawableTop`). No need for nested layouts.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko **Try**. It actually works. And it's a **fact**, not an opinion.

Comment: @KlingKlang **I know** that it works, same as **my variant**.  And **in fact**, that **I have checked with the tests**, adding proper viewgroups instead of trying to overoptimize it with having no nested viewgroups gives you much more control over the layout in charge of **totally no, or almost no penalty in performance**. Which is **for my opinion** completely worth it. That's how you should **express your opinion** instead of pushing it as a fact.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko But your **variant** to my approach requires useless nesting. Which is bad for performances. And it was **not** what **I** was suggesting.

Comment: @KlingKlang Please read my last comment to see why **it is not useless** before posting the next comment

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko Still useless, for me. There's people who love optimizations (mostly old-school developers, like me) and who don't (mostly young developers).

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#000000"

   >

<TextView
android:text="08:55"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:textSize="60sp"
android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
android:textColor="@android:color/white"
android:paddingTop="30dp"
android:gravity="center"/>

<TextView
android:text="Tuesday, August 23, 2016"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textSize="20sp"
android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
android:textColor="@android:color/white"
android:gravity="center"/>


<TextView
android:text="What have you been up to last 10 min?"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textSize="20sp"
android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
android:textColor="@android:color/white"
android:gravity="center"/>

<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:background="#000000"
>
 <!--UserGridLayout objects here-->
</GridLayout>

 <TextView
android:text="Skip"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:textSize="20sp"
android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
android:textColor="@android:color/white"
android:gravity="right"/>
```